# Multi-tenant plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, multi-tenant

Hi i would like to know is there any multi-tenant plugin for wordpress. I have already searched on this topic but i could not find the solution.

In my case i would like to create a core wordpress setup loaded with several themes and plugins and also i want to replicate the core wordpress sites to several copy. And the important thing is if i do any change in the core wordpress site (ie. adding any new plugin or theme etc.) i want to replicate the same to all the copy of wordpress sites. Is this possible ??

Any suggestions would be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multisite feature of Wordpress. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but sill i am facing some problems. I have installed the windows version bitnami-wordpress and the root master website works fine and it is running in the url http://localhost and i logged into the wordpress admin side and i tried to create a copy of the wordpress site in the url http://copy.localhost and it ends in Server not found page. I have also tried to change the url to http://localhost/copy after creating new site but it is not working. Do you have any ideas ??

Comment: Your server configuration probably can't resolve urls in the form 'something.localhost'. So you should choose 'sub-directories' method instead of 'sub-domains' when installing the network in the master website admin. I advise to make a fresh install of the master site with this setting for the network (a reconfiguration of the network afterwards is less easy).

Comment: Thanks buddy this works fine, i have added the corresponding url in vhost file ;)

Comment: I have just one more qeustion, if i activate any new theme or plugin it is reflected in all the other copy websites, is there any option to restrict this option to only one or to any selected copy websites ??.

Comment: You can activate or deactivate plugins and themes individually in the admin area of each website, but you can't select the websites affected directly from the network administration area. The "plugins enabler" plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/plugins-enabler/) could be useful, I didn't try it.